# Error java at array.Array

Tags: java, array, poo

Quiero conseguir la moda de un array, pero el codigo me tira un error y no se a que se debe, me estoy volviendo loco. La opcion mas facil seria cambiar el codigo pero este es el que mas entiendo, y ademas hay otras cosas que pense por mi propia cuenta y por eso insisto con este.

```
package testArray;

import java.util.Arrays;

import array.Array;
public class testArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int arreglo[] = {1,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,3,5};
        
        Array array1 = new Array(arreglo);
        
        
        
        
        System.out.println("La moda es:"+array1.traerModa()); -----------LINEA DE ERROR--------------

        
    

    }

}
```

Mi clase es la siguiente

```
package array;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array {
    private int vector [] ;
    
    public Array(int [] vector) {
        this.vector = new int[vector.length];
        this.vector=vector;
        
    }

    public int traerElMayor(int v[]){
        int mayor=vector[0];
        for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++) {
            if(vector[i]>mayor) {
                mayor=vector[i];
            }
        }
        return mayor;
    }
   public int traerModa() {
        int contador [] = new int[4];
        
        for(int i=0 ;i<vector.length;i++)
        {   
            contador[vector[i]] +=1;        -----------ACA ME CORTA LA EJECUCION--------------
        }
        int moda = traerElMayor(contador);
        return moda;
    
        
    }

}
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente, anteriormente en otro metodo tambien me tiraba el mismo error, pero se soluciono solo!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at array.Array.traerModa(Array.java:118)
    at testArray.testArray.main(testArray.java:20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu contador es un array de  4 elementos, pero tu `Array1` tiene un elemento con valor 5.

Así que intentas incrementar  `contador[5]`   y se queja de que es **"OutOfBounds"**, es decir que el indice de ese array es demasiado grande.

Comment: Ahii esta le cambie el tamaño al contador!! graciass

Answer (score 2):

Como bien menciona el usuario [@cruz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/188159/cruz) tienes un error al momento de declarar la variable `contador`, ya que la variable `Array1` tiene un `length` superior a lo declarado en `contador`. Esto produce que el programa quiera acceder a un índice del `contador` que es superior al `length` del mismo (por encima del límite), produciendo el error ***OutOfBounds***.

Ahora bien, he mirado tu código y si bien podrías llegar al resultado de esa manera, estás usando dos métodos para llegar a la moda:

Por lo mismo he modificado tu código y he obtenido la moda de un solo método en concreto:

```java
    public int traerModa() {
        //declaración y inicialización de variables
        int contador = 0; // con el contaremos las veces que un número se repite en el array
        int auxiliar = 0; // verificaremos con el el mayor contador
        int numeroModa = 0; // extraeremos el número que sea la moda

        //iniciamos un for, con el veremos número por número 
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            // con este for anidado veremos un número en concreto y compararemos
            // con todo el resto del array
            for (int j = 0; j < vector.length; j++) {
                if (vector[i] == vector[j]) { // si es que el número es el mismo
                    contador++; // aumentamos el contador en uno
                }
            }
            // miramos si el contador es superior al auxiliar
            if (contador > auxiliar) {
                // de ser así el auxiliar toma el valor de contador, ya que significa
                // que tenemos un número que podría ser la moda
                auxiliar = contador; 
                numeroModa = vector[i]; // tomamos el número en cuestión
            }
            contador = 0; // seteamos el contador a 0 nuevamente
        }
        return numeroModa; // retornamos el número moda
    }
```

---

Realicé un `for` anidado, el primero se encarga de sacar número por número, que comparamos con el `Array` completo en el segundo `for` el cual con ayuda de un contador, sabremos cual es el número que es la moda dentro del `Array` en concreto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera, el arreglo que desees de ver cual es su moda, podrá tener el `length` que gustes, sin tener que cambiar algo en tu código.